# How to make TabItem header support tab navigation

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

My window contains a TabControl which looks like below:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="A">
        // Content A
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="B">
        // Content B
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

When I use tab key to navigate, it will navigate from the current tab header and then the content of the current tab, it will not navigate to the next tab header. How to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard Shortcut Between Tabs On Tab Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096675/keyboard-shortcut-between-tabs-on-tab-control)

Comment: @MarkFeldman I don't find anything similar. Tab navigation should be the default behavior of the control, I don't think I need to do any keybinding. What's the default behavior of TabControl when I use tab key to navigate? Thanks!

Comment: The default behavior is Control-Tab switches between the tabs whereas Tab by itself switches focus between controls within the current tab. If you want to change this then I believe you have to use a key binding, although personally I wouldn't do this as it would change what would arguably be behavior expected by the user (at least in a WPF app).